# Htaccess + codeigniter: переадресация класса на поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте. По умолчанию в Code Igniter установлена схема URI: site.ru/class/...
А мне нужно сделать так: class.site.ru - подскажите, как сделать

Answer (score -2):

Для начало нужно настроить веб сервер для автоматического создания поддомена, после настроить .htaccess
В гугле достаточно уроков, так что, гугли.